# How to change LiteIDE menu language?

Tags: ide

I have downlaoded LiteIDE from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/liteide/files/) (liteidex27.2.1.linux-64-qt4.tar.bz2)

The problem is that  the menu is in German. I'm wondering how can I change the menu language to English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with X29 and fixed it by setting an environment variable.

To fix the problem permanently I put a batch into the bin directory and use that one instead of liteide.exe directly. The batch looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET LANG=en_US.utf8
start LiteIDE %*
```

(A similar approach involving `export LANG=...` and a bash script should work on Linux too)

I tried to define the same variable in system.env but there it didn't work so setting it before running LiteIDE is probably the better solution.

Another way to achieve the same is changing the options:

[image]

[image]

The third approach is to modify the `liteide.ini` which is located in .\LiteIDE\share\liteide\liteapp\config:

```
[%General]
Language=en_US
```